# Form field still validates falsely even after clean method override

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model which has a restricts the number of decimal places:

```
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

From it I create a `ModalForm` however I would like to cap the number of decimal places if they submitted something with more than 5 places. So I do a custom clean method:

```
def clean_lat(self):
    lat = self.cleaned_data['lat']
    return round(lat, 4)
```

But it still raises a `ValidationError` that I have more decimal places then allowed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what django version are you using ?

Comment: Can we see the actual error being produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two option to solve this.

First one is to override your modelform `init` method like this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['lat'].decimal_places = None
    self.fields['lat'].max_digits = None
```

This will disable the decimal places and max digit valididation by modelform. Then your `clean_lat` method should ensure ensure form data validation. Model will still truncate/ roundoff/ validate decimal value.

Second option is that remove `max_digits=8, decimal_places=5` from model and ensure validation in your forms `clean_lat` method. This can create problem if object is saved without using the `ModelForm`.

Answer (score -4):

the form.is_valid method do a very simple thing:

```
def full_clean(self):
    """
    Cleans all of self.data and populates self._errors and
    self.cleaned_data.
    """
    self._errors = ErrorDict()
    if not self.is_bound:  # Stop further processing.
        return
    self.cleaned_data = {}
    # If the form is permitted to be empty, and none of the form data has
    # changed from the initial data, short circuit any validation.
    if self.empty_permitted and not self.has_changed():
        return

    self._clean_fields()
    self._clean_form()
    self._post_clean()
```

I suggest you get into the source code(django/forms/forms.py), and the reason will be located quickly.